# Print layout of grids in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

Content displayed in divs that are set to col-md-* display stacked and 100% width when printed.  My current fix is to change the divs to col-xs-* and hope no one tries to view the page on a small device.

I need a bit of guidance on what I could add to the @print directive in print.less to make the print layout of col-sm-* to remain horizontal .  I understand that the pixel width of a printed page at 72dpi is in the 540px range, so this is why the page is wrapping on col-sm-*.  currently in my print css I have:

```
[class*="col-sm-"]{ float: left; }
```

Which works, but in possibly only a few cases, which meets my immediate need, but probably has unknown side effects. I already scale the font in my print css down to 96%, because it prints way too large by default vs. on screen. This means layouts that wrap on the screen would look fine when printed horizontally in the col-sm-* class, all the up to probably 11 columns side by side, accounting for page margin and grid padding for readability.

Edit: Here is a jsFiddle, but the behavior can't be replicated on there because of the way they render the html >>  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kB4yj/2/)

Comment: can you possibly get a jsFiddle going of your problem?

Comment: @aug I updated with a link, but you can't really demonstrate the behavior on jsFiddle.

Comment: You had your class nesting the wrong way round. [FTFY here](http://jsfiddle.net/kB4yj/3/)